# Why is a JSON file so much smaller than a .txt file with the same content?

Tags: json, export-to-csv

I am converting a JSON file (from an ajax call) into CSV.

When the JSON file is sent to me, it is 80kb.

When I save the contents of the JSON file into a .txt file, it becomes 291kb!

After converting the .txt file into a .csv file, it's 240kb.

How is the JSON file I received from an ajax call so much smaller a .txt file I created with identical content?  Is there some way to reduce the size of the end product?

EDIT:

This is how I am getting the file size.

1. I find the AJAX request, and check its file size.  [Link](https://i.gyazo.com/c2560ae9845cdb90a1920d42716c2f46.png).  As you can see, it is about 80kb.
2. I copy the source of the request.  [Link](https://i.gyazo.com/818c98d2990bcece9b7990e2a8b572c0.png).
3. Then I copy and paste the source into a blank .txt file.  The result is a .txt file that is 291 kb in size.

EDIT:

I don't think the .txt to .csv conversion problem is the issue, but here is my code:

```
import json
import csv
import re

with open('jjj.txt') as f:
    f = f.read()

parsed = json.loads(f)
unix_time = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)')

data = parsed['d']['tables'][0]['rows']
for i in data:
    for a in range(len(i)):
        if a > 39 and a < 46:
            if i[a] != None:
                mo = unix_time.search(i[a])
                i[a] = mo.group(1)


file = open('json.csv', 'w', newline='')
csvwriter = csv.writer(file)
csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

Comment: what tool were using to convert the files?

Comment: And from where did you get the file sizes?

Comment: There's no possible way to answer this without 1) seeing your code, 2) seeing sample input and 3) seeing sample output. We don't know a single thing about your app or code. So anything posted here would just be a wild guess.

Comment: Your JSON might have been compressed. See the network tab in the developer console of a browser.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information.  I posted my steps of retrieving the JSON file, and also my .txt to .csv conversion code.

Comment: this column is the "transferred" size. What has been transferred is a g-zipped version of the actual data.

Comment: Intrinsically, these three file formats are just storing trivial characters.I think encoding conversion is the problem. Why not try `iconv -f UTF-32 -t UTF-8 jjj.txt > smaller.txt` to check whether its size changed??

Comment: And at least, please give your python version and running environment such as operating system and origin file encoding. And make sure you've checked the encoding format of the outputted files.

Comment: @AntiMoron I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.  Python v3.6.2.  I'm using the default file encoding (basically opening a new .txt file, paste, save).  I tried saving at UTF-8, but still the same size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON is a string format used mostly for communication. If we want to save the JSON string in a file, it will be a text file. In this case, there will be no difference between JSON or any other content of the text file.

You are receiving a JSON string from your Ajax call, not a JSON file. You are receiving it over HTTP, and it is compressed (g-zipped). So you are comparing the size of the compressed text with the flat one which you are creating. Zip the file you are creating and you will get it down to almost the same size (depending on the compression tool and settings).

Comment: @AntiMoron Perhaps I should've chosen other wording. Read the first sentence of my second paragraph, I think it is clearer. I will delete the first sentence that you referred to.

Comment: You are right.  When I zipped `jjj.txt`, it became 74kb.  That's awesome but I can't convert a zip file into a csv file.  Is there some way to create a csv file that holds identical data but compressed into ~80kb in size?

Comment: I don't know why you are saving a JSON string into a file named csv. Anyway, text files usually compress about 70-80% which is what you're getting. No, there is no way -as far as I know- to compress a text file (JSON, CSV, or what have you) without actually.... hmmm, creating a compressed file. There are tools that hide the compression, so you don't see it, but that doesn't change the fact. Example, if you use a compressed hard drive, all files on it will be compressed and decompressed automatically without you seeing it. Tell us what you're trying to do so we help you.

Comment: @RacilHilan I am scraping another website's database (I will refer to them as 'they') and storing it in my own website's database.  They transfer their data through JSON files, through ajax calls.  In order to add their records into my own database, I need to convert their JSON files in CSV files.  There are hundreds of GBs of data to add, so I hope to keep the CSV files as small as possible.

Comment: That's not called website scraping. You're simply consuming their API (assuming they intentionally made it public). You should process the returned JSON strings and save them in a real database, not in text CSV files. Doing so renders your question irrelevant.

Comment: @RacilHilan It's a pretty secretive database and it's difficult to scrape everything all at once.  For example, they only allow 200 records to be displayed at a time.  So I need to manually request 200 records, copy the JSON file, and send it into my own database.  But you're right that I may be able to use the JSON files directly.  I didn't think of that for some reason, I don't need to convert from JSON to CSV...